# Is this probability function continuous?

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, continuity

I have a probability function shown below, and I was wondering if it is possible to set the right side equal to 0, then take the derivative of the right side with respect to $P_j{_r}$ and find the global maximum.  However, to do this the function should be continuous and I'm not sure if it is.

Assuming all variables other than $P_j{_r}$ are given constants, is this function continuous and is it possible to find the global maximum?

$$ Pr_j{_r}=\frac{y_j{_r}exp(\frac{x_j+x_r+b*log(P_j{_r})}{1-h})( \sum_{s=1}^R y_j{_s}exp(\frac{(x_j+x_s+b*log(P_j{_r}))}{1-h}))^-{^h}}{exp(I_0)+\sum_{r=1}^R\sum_{j=1}^Jy_j{_r}exp(\frac{x_j+x_r+b*log(P_j{_r})}{1-h})(\sum_{s=1}^Ry_j{_s}exp(\frac{x_j+x_r+b*log(P_j{_r})}{1-h}))^-{^h}} $$

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you're worrying if this function is just continous, rather than being worried for it being differentiable.

Comment: You can get proper formatting for functions like $\exp$ and $\log$ using `\exp` and `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.